# Center an image hyperlink within responsive background div

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to code an email. It contains a responsive div with background image and an image button at the center of that background. I want the image button to be exactly at the center. However, the button moves away from the center when tested on different devices with different viewport width.

https://jsfiddle.net/kevinsalgatar/7x3trcu6/

```css
div.container {
  background: url(https://gallery.mailchimp.com/38a79fccde10813ac5aad2f4d/images/6f1f0255-24a6-49a6-8a22-fc337c1d3430.png)no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div.button {
  position: max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.button>img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.button>a {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XejJw3Xgsr4">
      <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/38a79fccde10813ac5aad2f4d/images/780372ac-7648-4dd4-9a29-9bfc7ca6c54c.png" alt="780372ac-7648-4dd4-9a29-9bfc7ca6c54c.png"></a>
  </div>
  <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/38a79fccde10813ac5aad2f4d/images/6f1f0255-24a6-49a6-8a22-fc337c1d3430.png" style="visibility: hidden;" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably bacause you're using `-webkit-transform` only. Which is avaible only in browsers with Webkit engine. Try to add `transform`, `-moz-transform`, `-ms-transform` ...

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it didn't fix the problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
div.container {
    background: url(https://gallery.mailchimp.com/38a79fccde10813ac5aad2f4d/images/6f1f0255-24a6-49a6-8a22-fc337c1d3430.png)no-repeat;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```